# JQuery : Illegal Invocation Error While Taking Attribute Values from Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I Have A JQuery and AJAX call that works but it gives an error as follow:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)

In this case i want to get the values from custom attributes as i created

```
<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='delete_subject_function(this)' id='question_delete' value='$subject_id3' data-class='$class_id3' data-school='$schools_id3'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
```

And to get the value from button i using following code but it gives me an error.

For Example i want to take attribute value data-school , data-class and value so, for that i am using  e.getAttribute('data-school');  like code.

Here's the JQUERY Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    delete_subject_function = function(e){
        var school_id = e.getAttribute('data-school');
        var class_id = e.getAttribute('data-class');
        var value = e.getAttribute('value');
        if(school_id){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete_subject.php',
                data:{delete_subject:school_id,class_id :class_id,value :value},
                success:function(data){
                    refresh_subject();
                }
            }); 
        }else{
           alert("Subject that you want to delete has no ID");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you read the multiple dupes here in S.O

Comment: Thanks For Reply @Dagon And giving time from your valuable time But i doesn't clear that what you want to say..

Comment: I've removed the *php* tag for you. Please take care about the generated tags when creating a question. They are used as filters to find questions, one is able to answer. You can manage the selected tags on yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but you can try restructuring like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id^=question_delete']).click(function(){
    var school_id = $(this).data('school');
    var class_id = $(this).data('class');
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);
    if(value.length){
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'delete_subject.php',
        data:{'delete_subject' : school_id},
        success:function(data){
          if (data.length) alert(data);
          refresh_subject();
        }
      }); 
    }else{
      alert("Subject that you want to delete has no ID");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
 <button class='btn btn-danger' id='question_delete' value='$subject_id3' data-class='$class_id3' data-school='$schools_id3'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
```

---

Notes:

(1) Use `$('[id^=what_it_starts_with'])` to bind the click event to all elements with an ID that "starts with" `question_delete` (for example)

Comment: Thanks @gibberish for reply and problem has been solved and Code is working successfully.